# Java Comparing Two Arrays for Login

Tags: java, arrays, authentication, control-flow

I'm having a problem while comparing the username and password array. I'm trying to find a solution for hours, tried many things but couldn't be able to achieve success.

Whenever I try entering username input as **admin** and password input as **123**, it prints **"Login Success! Loading the menu..."** but when I try username input as **john** and password input as **512** as a test value, *it prints a successful login message*.

But username input as **john** and password input as **123** prints invalid message. I couldn't be able to solve what's happening here.

My purpose is that to compare two arrays to log in successfully. For example:

- username: admin, password: 123
- username: john, password: 456
- username: alina, password: 789

Edit: I also tried .equals() method in several ways but didn't work.

```
    public static boolean UserLogin() {
        String[] username = {"admin", "john", "alina"};
        String[] password = {"123", "456", "789"};
        String user, pass;
        boolean isValid = false;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
        user = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
        pass = input.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < username.length; i++) {
            if (username[i].indexOf(user) == password[i].indexOf(pass)) {
                isValid = true;
                System.out.println("Login Success! Loading the menu...");
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid username or password, please contact your Database Administrator for " +
                        "support!");
                break;
            }
        }

        return isValid;
    }
```

Comment: This is an antipattern called _parallel arrays_. Instead, create a `class User` with `username` and `password` properties.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- still he is using indexOf which is not as per the use case

Comment: Please double check what [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) does. This is improper usage of that method. I would recommend looking into using a [Map](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-map) since your values have a key-value relationship.

Comment: @TimHunter Oh, I get the idea behind the indexOf() method right now. Thanks. I will try using a Map too.

Comment: @Cednuc I'll clarify, your Usernames should be the key and your Passwords the value. This will mean your Username will need checks to make sure it is unique and not already inserted into your Map if you plan to add functionality to add additional Username-Password pairs through the console. If you don't check, it will just override the Password when you re-use the same Username.

Comment: @TimHunter It makes sense. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use a map for this.

- the map will return `null` if the user doesn't exist so the check will fail.
- or it will return the password for the user and the password check will fail.
- Returns are immediate after the result message is displayed.

```
static Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();
    
String[] username = { "admin", "john", "alina" };
String[] password = { "123", "456", "789" };
// build the map.
for (int i = 0; i < username.length; i++) {
    users.put(username[i], password[i]);
}
userLogin();

    
public static boolean userLogin() { 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
    String user = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
    String pass = input.nextLine();
    
    String password = users.get(user);
    if (pass.equals(password)) {
        System.out.println("Login Success! Loading the menu...");
        return true;
    }
    System.out.println(
            "Invalid username or password, please contact your Database Administrator for "
                    + "support!");
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: A comment above and below mentioned to use HashMap and here is the implementation of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```java
package days.temp;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(UserLogin());
    }

    public static boolean UserLogin() {
        String[] username = {"admin", "john", "alina"};
        String[] password = {"123", "456", "789"};
        String user, pass;
        boolean isValid = false;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
        user = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
        pass = input.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < username.length; i++) {
            if(username[i].equals(user) && password[i].equals(pass)){
                isValid = true;
                System.out.println("Login Success! Loading the menu...");
                break;
            }
        }

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but whenever I try this with an else block, it still returns false when I enter input john as username and 456 as password. I didn't understand why.

Comment: @Cednuc you have to remove the else part. I updated the complete code.

Comment: If you are allowed to use a data structure other than an array, better to use a HashMap data structure in Java collections API.

Comment: Thanks for your time! But I'm curious about whether I can print a message when one of the inputs is not matched with each other or not.

Comment: @Cednuc you can write your message depends on the return from the UserLogin() method

Answer (score 0):

Well as per your logic your are using indexOf which usually return the match index or -1.
As per your case when you are trying jhon and 512

username[i].indexOf(jhon) is returning -1 when index is 0
password[i].indexOf(512) is returning -1 when index is 0

they both are equal so you get login.

I will suggest you to use username[i].equals(user) as this is correct way to match strings. Even If user have space in input please make sure you use username[i].equals(user.trim());

Comment: Oh, didn't realize the return values of the indexOf() method. Thank you.